# Weight limits for airliner bogie 6 landing gear

Tags: aircraft-design

I have been unable to find the weight limits for 6-wheel bogie landing gear? I did find that for 4-wheel bogie landing gear, is for aircraft 200,000 lbs or greater. But what is the limits for 6-wheel bogie landing gear? Thankyou for the help.

Comment: I haven't looked into the specific limits, but as it's the load per wheel that is limiting the weight, a first guess would be 6/4 * 200,000 lbs